# Python: (re)storing an initialized object from/to string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to store an **initialized** object as a string and restore it without having to initialize it again.

It seems to be a rare case and I don't like it but it would be helpful. Pseudo-code below.

Any idea?

```
obj = default_function(1, 2, 3)
if a:
  obj = a_function(1, 2, 3)
elif b:
  obj = b_function(1, 2, 3)

obj_as_str = store_object_as_string(obj)
obj = restore_object_from_string(obj_as_str)
print(obj)  # output, because already initialized before storing
```

Comment: Why as **string** in particular? What about rather using [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)?

Comment: If you don't want to go via a pickle file you can use some `__dict__` and `JSON`  magic. But you'd need to re-initialize the object from `JSON` (e.g., add a `from_json`static method). Also the object needs to support ` __dict__`, so you might have to implement that as well...